# How to pass more than one values as parameter to sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

I have one big SQL query and I want to pull out some data using that query

```
declare @Period VARCHAR(10)  = 'MTD'
declare @Date DATETIME = '2011-08-31'
```

and I have a big `select statement` where I'm passing above parameters and it executes the output.

Now I have 10 different dates which I need to pass here each time to see the result.

How can I pass those date to above parameter `declare @Date DATETIME` how can I hard code it ?

So my desired output will be for those selected dates, give me hint for at least 3 dates ?

Comment: do you want to run query once with 10 parameters, or run the query 10 times with 1 different parameter?

Comment: Currently I'm running sql query 10 times by putting different different dates manually and see the result  ,
but i want something by using i can declare those 10 dates for the variable declare @Date DATETIME and it gives me result .
like we do using `Between` keywork for two parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a table-valued parameter. First, create a type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Dates AS TABLE(d DATE);
```

Now your stored procedure can take this type as a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
  @d dbo.Dates READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT t.columns
    FROM dbo.tableName AS t
    INNER JOIN @d AS d
    ON t.[date] = d.d;
END
GO
```

Then from your application you can pass this parameter in as a `DataTable`, for example.

Comment: example is missing please complete it .
Thanks very much :)

Comment: example is missing please complete it .
Not in application :( I want to directly execute this sql query.  
Thanks very much :)

Comment: @ashuthinks you need to provide more information. How does your SQL query *get* the list of dates you want to check? They have to come from somewhere.